# Unable to SSL Pass through Ingress Nginx Controller

Tags: java, nginx, ssl, kubernetes, nginx-ingress

I have a Java [Spring Boot Application](https://github.com/kahootali/SpringJavaMonitoringApp) and I have configured the server to run on SSL and it is mandatory.

```
server:
  port: 8443
  ssl:
    enabled: true
    key-store-type: pkcs12
    key-store: ${KEYSTORE}
    key-password: ${KEYSTORE_PASSWORD}
    key-store-password: ${KEYSTORE_PASSWORD}
    client-auth: need
```

I have created a cert for my domain `*.kahootali.com` from LetsEncrypt certificate and created a p12 file for the keystore by running

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -CAfile ca.crt -in cert.pem -inkey key.pem -certfile cert.pem -out kstore.p12
```

I want to expose it on Kubernetes using Ingress Nginx Controller, so I have created secret by

```
kubectl create secret generic store --from-file=kstore.p12
```

I have deployed application, can see the [deployment files,](https://github.com/kahootali/SpringJavaMonitoringApp/tree/main/deploy) and when I port-forward local 8443 to its service's 8443 and run

```
curl -iv --cacert ca.crt --cert mediator_cert.pem --key mediator_key.pem --resolve 'spring-app.kahootali.com:8443:127.0.0.1' https://spring-app.kahootali.com:8443/
```

It works fine and returns

```
* Added spring-app.kahootali.com:8444:127.0.0.1 to DNS cache
* Hostname spring-app.kahootali.com was found in DNS cache
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to spring-app.kahootali.com (127.0.0.1) port 8444 (#0)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: ca.crt
  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server key exchange (12):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Request CERT (13):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server finished (14):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client key exchange (16):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, CERT verify (15):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS change cipher, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* SSL connection using TLSv1.2 / ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
* ALPN, server did not agree to a protocol
* Server certificate:
*  subject: CN=*.kahootali.com
*  start date: Feb 11 10:27:47 2021 GMT
*  expire date: May 12 10:27:47 2021 GMT
*  subjectAltName: host "spring-app.kahootali.com" matched cert's "*.kahootali.com"
*  issuer: C=US; O=Let's Encrypt; CN=R3
*  SSL certificate verify ok.
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: spring-app.kahootali.com:8444
> User-Agent: curl/7.58.0
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 404 
HTTP/1.1 404 
< X-Application-Context: application:8443
X-Application-Context: application:8443
< Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< Date: Sun, 14 Feb 2021 14:29:47 GMT
Date: Sun, 14 Feb 2021 14:29:47 GMT

< 
* Connection #0 to host spring-app.kahootali.com left intact
{"timestamp":1613312987350,"status":404,"error":"Not Found","message":"No message available","path":"/"}
```

But when I create an Ingress for it and ssl-passthrough it

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: spring-monitoring-app
  labels:
    app: spring-monitoring-app
  annotations:
    ingress.kubernetes.io/force-ssl-redirect: "true"
    ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-passthrough: "true"
spec:
  rules:
    - host: spring-app.kahootali.com
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            backend:
              serviceName: spring-monitoring-app
              servicePort: http
  tls:
    - hosts:
      - spring-app.kahootali.com
      secretName: tls-cert
```

It gives `ERR_BAD_SSL_CLIENT_AUTH_CERT` on browser and in app Debug level logs, it gives

```
Error during SSL handshake
java.io.IOException: EOF during handshake.
The SNI host name extracted for this connection was [spring-app.kahootali.com]
Handshake failed during wrap
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Empty server certificate chain
```

Comment: As per [the docs](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/tls/#ssl-passthrough) **SSL Passthrough** feature is disabled by default. In order to enable it you need to start your **nginx-ingress controller** with `--enable-ssl-passthrough` flag. Make sure you didn't forget about it.

Answer (score 5):

*I'm posting my comment as an answer for better visibility:*

As per  [the docs](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/tls/#ssl-passthrough)  **SSL Passthrough**  feature is disabled by default. In order to enable it you need to start your  **nginx-ingress controller**  with  `--enable-ssl-passthrough`  flag. Make sure you didn't forget about it.

You may also take a look at this [troubleshooting steps](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/troubleshooting/#troubleshooting) to verify your **nginx-ingress controller** configuration.

Please let me know if it helps.